# How to tweak the return type of an existing type

Tags: typescript

Say for example there's the following type:

```
type Conditionalize = (...args: any[]) => string
```

Is it possible to tweak the type above a little bit without having to copy & paste the entire type again? something like:

```
type ConditionalizeNum = ChangeReturnType<Conditionalize, number>
```

Now `ConditionalizeNum` is equal to:

```
type ConditionalizeNum = (...args: any[]) => number
```

I am doing that because I am trying to tweak an existing type which isn't created by me, but by the library maintainers I'm using (React).

Basically there's a type called FC which I want to tweak a little bit, so it can accept the returning value of strings and numbers instead of just `ReactElement` | `null`.

Answer (score 0):

You just have to create a function type with the parameters of `Conditionalize` and the return type you want, for example:

```
type Conditionalize = (...args: any[]) => string;

type ConditionalizeNum = (...args: Parameters<Conditionalize>) => number;
```

For more info about the `Parameter` type, see [here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype)

A more generic utility would be the following:

```
type ReplaceReturnType<R, T extends () => any> = (...args: Parameters<T>) => R;
```

Comment: Great, one solution, but sometimes the function signature is more complicated than this one, sometimes these functions are generics. We should have a helper utility for this purpose

Comment: @Normal you just have to pass the generics to the `Parameters` type like `type ConditionalizeNum = (...args: Parameters<React.PropsWithChildren<{ foo: number }>>) => number;`, nothing complicated

Comment: "sometimes the function signature is more complicated than this one" any use cases you think are important should be represented in the question post, so the scope of the question doesn't expand in response to answers.